# yocto build failing with error ERROR: oe_runmake failed

Tags: c, gcc, yocto, beagleboneblack, bitbake

I am trying to build yocto kirkstone version on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS running over VMWare workstation.

I followed the steps mentioned in the yocto project quick build page.
https://docs.yoctoproject.org/brief-yoctoprojectqs/index.html

I got build errors after running "bitbake core-image-sato" command

```
{standard input}: Error: .size expression for _Z12gen_addv8sf3P7rtx_defS0_S0_ does not evaluate to a constant
g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1136: insn-emit.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
rm gcc.pod
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vijay/yocto/poky/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/gcc-cross-x86_64/11.3.0-r0/build/gcc'
make: *** [Makefile:4456: all-gcc] Error 2
ERROR: oe_runmake failed
WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/vijay/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross_11.3.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1076 tasks of which 0 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
/home/vijay/yocto/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross_11.3.bb:do_compile
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

'''

could you please guide what might be the issue. any yocto specific community page available to discuss such build issues?

Comment: "killed" means I have to ask how much memory is available

Comment: * "  Error: .size expression for _Z12gen_addv8sf3P7rtx_defS0_S0_ does not evaluate to a constant "* can you clean completely your build and try again? Seems that something is corrupted/not uptodate here.

Comment: @user253751 I have configured 4GB RAM and 100GB disk space for the linux virtual machine where i am running this yocto build

Comment: 4GB RAM ??? Well, good luck. If you can increase to at least 16 would be better. Or, type PARALLEL_MAKE ?= "-j 1" in your build/conf/local.conf